# Selecting removing a registry noteproperty

Tags: powershell, registry

I want to delete a selected (note) property from a registry key.  I have a working solution but I believe it can be further simplified into a single line.  This machine has Access 2013.  Windows puts a registry entry into the key's MRU (most recently used) list.  I want to remove a particular file reference.

**Here's the registry key export(.reg file) with the files as Item ##'s**

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\File MRU]
"Item 1"="[F00000000][T01D1DDCCE172A971][O00000000]*C:\\timetools\\timedb.accdb"
"Item 2"="[F00000000][T01D1DDCC9CA60D50][O00000000]*C:\\Users\\p64576\\Documents\\Accounts\\accounts.accdb"
```

**Here is the inspection of the key and its types:**

```
Get-ItemProperty HKCU:"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\File MRU" | gm

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name         MemberType   Definition                                                                                                  
----         ----------   ----------                                                                                                  
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                              
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                                           
GetType      Method       type GetType()                                                                                              
ToString     Method       string ToString()                                                                                           
Item 1       NoteProperty string Item 1=[F00000000][T01D1DDCCE172A971][O00000000]*C:\timetools\timedb.accdb                         
Item 2       NoteProperty string Item 2=[F00000000][T01D1DDCC9CA60D50][O00000000]*C:\Users\p64576\Documents\Accounts\accounts.accdb   
PSChildName  NoteProperty string PSChildName=File MRU                                                                                 
PSDrive      NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=HKCU                                                                                    
PSParentPath NoteProperty string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\...
PSPath       NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access...
PSProvider   NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

**Here's my solution. Can someone recommend a more elegant solution?**

```
cls
$pset=get-itemproperty HKcu:"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\File MRU" 
$pset.psobject.properties | where-object -property value -like '*timedb*' |
     Remove-ItemProperty $pset.PSPath  -confirm
```